# What is a regex which matches exactly m to n characters but not more?

Tags: regular-expressions

`StringCases["abcdefg hi jkl mn opq rstuv w xy z ", RegularExpression["[a-z]{1,3}"]]`

returns

`{"abc", "def", "g", "hi", "jkl", "mn", "opq", "rst", "uv", "w", "xy", "z"}`

so it actually chops the first match of `RegularExpression["[a-z]*"]` into pieces of up to 3 characters (the max of the quantifier `{1,3}`).

I want a regular expression which does not do that but **rather considers the findings of** `RegularExpression["[a-z]*"]` **which mismatch the quantifier** `{1,3}` **as mismatches**. It should be greedy before applying specialized quantifiers.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. "[a-z]{1,3}"  does not first do "[a-z]*" but it tries to match 1 to 3 characters and this is exactly what you observe.  Further your question is not clear to me, what do you mean by: "which mismatch the quantifier {1,3} as mismatches".  Do you mean you want to match a character string that is longer than 3 characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must say what shall come before and after the 1–3 characters, for example a word boundary `\\b`:

```
StringCases["abcdefg hi jkl mn opq rstuv w xy z ", 
            RegularExpression["\\b[a-z]{1,3}\\b"]]

(*    {"hi", "jkl", "mn", "opq", "w", "xy", "z"}    *)
```

Alternatively, [split the string](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html) and then select the substrings you want:

```
Select[StringSplit["abcdefg hi jkl mn opq rstuv w xy z "], 
       1 <= StringLength[#] <= 3 &]

(*    {"hi", "jkl", "mn", "opq", "w", "xy", "z"}    *)
```

Answer (score 6):

We could test for the negation of the pattern ("mismatches") by using negative look-behind and look-ahead [assertions](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC20).  They can be used to discard any matches of `[a-z]{1,3}` that are preceded or followed a character that would also match `[a-z]`:

```
matches = StringCases @ RegularExpression @
  "(?<![a-z])[a-z]{1,3}(?![a-z])";
```

So then:

```
"abcdefg hi jkl mn opq rstuv w xy z " // matches
(* {hi,jkl,mn,opq,w,xy,z} *)

"abcdefg_hi_jkl_mn_opq_rstuv_w_xy_z_" // matches
(* {hi,jkl,mn,opq,w,xy,z} *)
```

If we would rather not repeat the target pattern three times, we could use named [groups](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC16) and [backreferences](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC19) (although for a short pattern like `[a-z]` this is probably overkill):

```
matches2 = StringCases @ RegularExpression @
  "(?<!(?<p>[a-z]))(?&p){1,3}(?!(?&p))";

"abcdefg hi jkl mn opq rstuv w xy z " // matches2
(* {hi,jkl,mn,opq,w,xy,z} *)

"abcdefg_hi_jkl_mn_opq_rstuv_w_xy_z_" // matches2
(* {hi,jkl,mn,opq,w,xy,z} *)
```

All of this syntax is described by the [PCRE pattern documentation](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#groupsassubroutines).  The WL documentation page [Working With String Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#274403895) states that PCRE is the library used to implement regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, your look-behind & look-ahead are much better (and versatile) than [what I wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246554/26598).

Comment: @Roman Thanks, and I quite like your solutions as well.  Indeed, should the OP's circumstances permit I think your word boundary solution is superior on the grounds of simplicity and fewer hieroglyphics :)  I was originally going to add my answer as a comment on yours but (as site regulars will have observed) I was _never_ going to fit what I wanted to say into a comment :D